# How to determine if there is enough power supply wattage for a video card?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, desktop-computer

I'm a complete newbie to computers.

I recently found a graphics card that takes a 300 watt power source and I don't wish to spend $150 dollars on something that won't work or will break my computer.

Here is an image of my power source sticker.

Will this give the required amount of power?

[image: image of power supply]

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Check the manufacturer's specs on the graphics card, and check the current demand (pun intended) for your CPU and other hardware, *for each voltage required*. The specs for the PS show 66 W at 3.3 V, 150 W at 5 V and 360 W at 12 V, for a *total* of 576 W **if the load were evenly distributed across all supplies**, but that is an unfounded assumption. Offhand, there does not seem to be sufficient power left for the GPU.

Comment: The 300W is the suggested power supply its not the required power supply.

Answer (score 2):

I calculate 408W (12V * (16 amps + 18 amps)) on your 12V rails, which is the rail your GPU will use. It probably can't actually do that do to efficiency challenges, which explains why the PSU is only advertised as 500 watts.

The GPU gets power from the slot it plugs into, and when that's insufficient, is supplemented by up to two extra power connections. See if you can use the connections from the second 12V rail (18 amps) for these. I found [an answer on SU](https://superuser.com/a/340070/68111) that discusses the *why* of this suggestion.

A system with access to 34 amps of 12V current should be fine with most GPUs!

I'm assuming the first 12V rail is being used for things like the CPU, fans, drives, etc., and that the second rail is underutilized by default. There's an [EE SE site](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) that may be able to tell you how your PSU is designed by looking at pictures of its internals. You'd just need a screwdriver and camera (after reading their FAQ to see if it's on-topic). :)

Comment: @Trevor No problem. Can you update your question with the model of your GPU?